# changing python interpreter in Spyder IDE, I can not upload different python exe(Windows)

Tags: python, spyder

While trying to change the python interpret in Spyder, I cannot access below folder's python.exe.

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0

[image: Spyder python interpreter add menu from preferences menu]

[image: pop up message from Spyder]